# How to check if missing values are predictive?

Tags: python, statistics, missing-data

In the course, I saw how we can analyze missing values.

[image: plots]

```
def analyse_na_value(df, var):
  df = df.copy()
  # let's make an interim variable that indicates 1 if the
  # observation was missing or 0 otherwise
  df[var] = np.where(df[var].isnull(), 1, 0)
  tmp = df.groupby(var)['SalePrice'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
  tmp.plot(kind="barh", y="mean", legend=False,
         xerr="std", title="Sale Price", color='green')
  plt.show()
```

Under this plots was the description "This suggests that data being missing could be a good predictor of Sale Price".

As I understand it means that instead of imputing or deleting we can use this value as it is. Of course, for some algorithms like RandomForest.

I decided to write a function that compares two distributions taken from the target variable. One that contains missing values and another doesn't. I tried two tests Kolmogorov–Smirnov test and Mann–Whitney U test.

```
def test_missing_values(feature: pd.Series, target_feature: pd.Series, random_seed: int = 42) -> None:
  np.random.seed(random_seed)
  data_with_missing_values = target_feature[feature.isna()]
  data_without_missing_values = target_feature[~feature.isna()]
  sample_size = max(len(data_with_missing_values), len(data_without_missing_values))
  sample_with_missing_values = np.random.choice(data_with_missing_values, replace=True, size=sample_size)
  sample_without_missing_values = np.random.choice(data_without_missing_values, replace=True, size=sample_size)
  return ks_2samp(sample_with_missing_values, sample_without_missing_values).pvalue
```

I expected that it will give me a statisticaly significant difference ONLY for Alley feature (as it is shown on the plot) but it also gives it to LotFrontage feature.

All in all:

1. Is something wrong with my tests?
2. Is it a good idea to do this type of analysis?

Comment: How big are you sample sizes? This seems like a methodological question - voting to migrate to CrossValidated.

Comment: It is about 800-1000.

Comment: With that many samples, it's likely detecting a small effect size.